# zsh autocompletion of my own function

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm trying to write a shortcut for a frequently visited directory so that I can eliminate`cd` (I know, I know, but I'm lazy).

So I wrote a function in my .zshrc that does this:

```
progs () {
  if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    cd /Volumes/data/progs
  else
    cd /Volumes/data/progs/$1
  fi
}
```

The intention being that if I jus type `progs` I go to the top level directory, but if I type `progs foo` it cd's to the `'.../progs/foo'` directory. However, I'd like to have the autocompletion system allow me to do a `<tab>` after `progs` to simulate the behavior of cd.

I've written a helper function:

```
function _progs() {
  _alternative "dirs:user directory:($(ls /Volumes/data/progs/$1))"
}
```

and then used:

```
compdef _progs progs
```

That worked fine until I created directories with spaces in them. Now, it list every word as the option not every directory.

How do I tell the autocomplete subsystem to list all files/directories as if I was completing "cd"?

BTW I do know about `cdpath` and that's fine, but I still have to type `cd progs <tab>`. I also tried the `_files` builtin instead of running `ls` in my helper function, but I can't get the `_files` builtin to accept a different directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape characters using `"dirs:user directory:($(ls -b /Volumes/data/progs/$1))"`.

This solves the space issue for completion but after some testing I found that when it encounters a directory with a `'` character in it, it errors out with `unmatched '`.
Normally I'd pipe that to `sed` but you'd be dealing with two levels of character escaping there as well, so that might prove a bit difficult.
If you know you won't ever create any directories with quotation marks in their name you're probably good, and otherwise you'll have to figure out how to escape those.

I do have a (much simpler) solution to what you're trying to achieve though: dir aliases.

simply add this to, say your alias file:

```sh
if [[ -r /Volumes/data/progs ]]; then
  progs=/Volumes/data/progs
  : ~progs
fi
```

And now you'll be able to access your directory typing `~progs` just like you would be able to go to your home directory with `~`. Works with completion out of the box at the cost of one extra keystroke.

Or just install `autojump`.

Comment: I tried the suggestion you have with the ```-b``` option but it still doesn't work for directories with a space. I thought it might be because I'd aliased ```ls``` to ```exa``` but using ```/bin/ls -b ...``` didn't work either. I'll try out ```autojump``` but now I'm on a mission to figure this autocomplete thing. It's got to be something rather simple I'm just not understanding in the dense documentation.

Comment: Odd. Using the `-b` flag worked for me when I tested it. But yeah, unfortunately I'm not well versed enough with autocompletion to know what's going on either.

Answer (score 0):

`_files` will accept a different directory if you pass it with `-W`, for example:

```
compdef '_files -W /Volumes/data/progs' progs
```